# function Recursive countdown

Tags: python

Define a function called count_down that accepts 1 argument. When you call count_down(3) , the output should be like this: 3... 2... 1... 0!.

My code is below:

```
def count_down(start):
    """
    Counting down a sequence with a skip value,
    from a defined start point in reversed order.

    Args:
        start: start loop index.
        skip: number to skip over.

    Returns:
        (list): skipped list.

    """
    return [num for num in reversed(range(start + 1)) ]



print(count_down(3))
print(count_down(4))
```

but the output is
[3, 2, 1, 0]
[4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
How to get the format like the format in question describes:
3... 2... 1... 0!

Comment: What is the first thing you should consider when writing a recursive function?

Comment: Where did that docstring come from?  It doesn't match the description of the problem you gave -- was it part of the problem, or did you copy and paste it from someplace else?

Comment: Your function is not recursive and I don't see anywhere that says that it's supposed to be...

Comment: try `print("... ".join(map(str, count_down(3))) + "!")`

Comment: just countdown like input 5, output 5 4 3 2 1, but I hope the output is 5...4...3...2...1...0!

Comment: Samwize thank you! you are so wise guy!!

Answer (score 1):

With any recursive function you need to think about the condition that will cause it to come to an end.  In this case when `start` is 0 you are done, so at that point it is time to print out your special case ("0!") and return. In other cases, you want to print the current value of `start` then call `count_down` again with `start` minus 1.

Example:

```
def count_down(start):
    if start == 0:
        print("0!")
        return
    print(start, end="...")
    count_down(start -1)
        
count_down(3)
```

Output:

```
3...2...1...0!
```

Answer (score 0):

print("... ".join(map(str, count_down(3))) + "!")

–by Samwise